# How to loop through Immutable List like forEach?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, immutable.js

I would like to loop through Immutable `List`, I used `List.map` to do it, it can be worked, but not good. is there are a better way? Because I just check each element in array, if the element match my rule, I do something, just like `Array.forEach`, I don't want to return anything like `Array.map`.

for example, it is my work now:

```
let currentTheme = '';
let selectLayout = 'Layout1';
let layouts = List([{
  name: 'Layout1',
  currentTheme: 'theme1'
},{
  name: 'Layout2',
  currentTheme: 'theme2'
}])


layouts.map((layout) => {
  if(layout.get('name') === selectLayout){
     currentTheme = layout.get('currentTheme');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method `List.forEach` exists for Immutable.js lists.

However, a more functional approach would be using the method `List.find` as follows:

```
let selectLayoutName = 'Layout1';
let layouts = List([Map({
  name: 'Layout1',
  currentTheme: 'theme1'
}),Map({
  name: 'Layout2',
  currentTheme: 'theme2'
})])


selectLayout = layouts.find(layout => layout.get('name') === selectLayoutName);
currentTheme = selectLayout.get('currentTheme')
```

Then your code doesn't have side-effects.

Comment: Thanks! List find is like `Array.filter`, that what I need :)

Comment: The difference is that ```List.find``` returns the first match, while ```Array.filter``` provide a list of all elements that satisfies the condition.

Comment: @SevenLee `List.find` is pretty much like `Array.find` and `List.filter` is like `Array.filter`. It is important to remember it.