# Can I loop over an immutable.List, immutable.Set or Javascript Array or Set using same code?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm working on some NodeJS code that uses many different "lists" of items.  The underlying implementation uses including Immutable.List, Immutable.Set, Javascript Array and Javascript Set.

For reasons I won't go into, I would like to be able to loop over these items without regard to the underlying collection.

Some background might be useful.  For Array, I can use the following to loop over a Javascript Array.

```
let anArray = [ new SomeObj(), new SomeObj(), ... ]
for(let idx=0; idx < anArray.length; idx++){
    let someObj = anArray[idx];
    // ... etc
    if (someCondition) break;
}
```

For the Immutable.List, I need to use the Immutable.List.size property (instead of the length property) and use "Immutable.List.get" function as follows:

```
const immutable = require('immutable');

let aList = immutable.List([ new SomeObj(), new SomeObj(), ... ]);
for(idx=0; idx < aList.size; idx++){
    var item = aList.get(idx);
    // ... etc
    if (someCondition) break;
}
```

The looping logic is VERY close except for some small differences.

For those who would suggest the natural answer of using the forEach() method that is available on each of these objects.  The normal Javascript [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method doesn't handle breaking out of the loop (the [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method is needed for that situation).  The Immutable.List is based on a [Immutable.Collection.forEach](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/forEach) that does support "breaking" out of the loop so this might work but would require wrapping the Javascript objects into a Immutable sequence/collection.  I'm new to using the Immutable library so there might be another approach that is well known to those familiar with Immutable.

The approach I'm considering is described next.
I'm thinking of a utility function that provides the solution as follows:

```
for(let idx=0, looper=new Looper(aListOrSet); idx < looper.length(); idx++){
    var item = looper.get(idx);
    // ... etc
    if (someCondition) break;
}
```

Some things I've looked at include:

- [How to loop through Immutable List like forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692999/how-to-loop-through-immutable-list-like-foreach)
- [Immutable.Collection.forEach](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/forEach)
- [Immutable Sequences](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Seq) - This might be the trick.  I would have to convert the Javascript objects to an immutable sequence, but this might work.

Has anyone else tried to solve this, and if so how did they solve this problem?

Comment: When implementing my solution, I realized that Javascript Set doesn't provide a way to get an item in the set based on an index.  So I created a class called Looper with three methods constructor(anObj), length() caches (if necessary) and returns length, and get(idx) that returns an item at a given index.  I'll update the question to reflect this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop. This allows you operate on any [Iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol) object, which includes built-in collections as well as Immutable.js collections.

```
for (let element of collection) {
    // do something with element
    if (someCondition) {
        break;
    }
}
```

It doesn't give you access to the index of iteration like a regular `for` loop or `forEach` would, but that's easy enough to keep track of yourself:

```
let i = 0;
for (let element of collection) {
    // do something with element
    if (someCondition) {
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

You might also want to read [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break). It lists a couple solutions including `for...of` that should work with all the collections you want to use:

- Wrap the loop in `try` and throw an exception to break
- Use `.some()` and `return true` to break

Answer (score 0):

You could prototype and create your own list that had a length function that returns the size. You can also override through prototype the forEach method on an array to break out.

The only other way which I can think of that isn't super clean, is to get the length or size of the object before calling the function that loop over the object and send it in as a parameter.